# Oracle SQL find string in a string (reversed)

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL, I have a query returning a list of distinct Projects and what Programme they're associated with, and a query returning a list of distinct active Programmes and the Programme key.
In the past a Project could have multiple Programmes so the Project table looks like this:

```
PROJECT   PROGRAMME KEY (varchar2)
AAA            55171; 55174; 55175
BBB            55173
CCC            55178; 55172;
```

So a project with multiple programmes shows the key for each separated by a semi colon

And the Programme table looks like this

```
PROGRAMME   PROGRAMME KEY (number)
XXX              55171
YYY              55172
ZZZZ             55173
```

Since a data cleanse where I got rid of old programmes, if a Project is now showing multiple programmes, only one of them should be an active programme which would match one of the programmes in my second list.

I want to be able to see if the Programme Key in the Project table matches any of the Programme keys in the Programme table and return that key.

So in short, on the Project table (first query) which of the Programme keys is present in the Programme table (second query)

Comment: Fix your data model so you are not returning multiple values in a string.

Comment: Are you sure each semicolon-separated string (not even; according to the posted sample, "semicolon AND SPACE separated string) contains exactly one programme key present in the second table? If "yes" - how can you be sure? If "no" - what should be done where a PROJECT doesn't match any programme key from the second table? Or when it matches two or more such program keys?

Comment: Will program key always be the same number of characters? Or could you have 55 and 55173 as program keys?

Comment: - I'm not able to fix the data model unfortunately, its controlled by the PPM tool supplier and even then the security around it at my work makes it impossible. 
- No, some of the projects are super old (which is why they have the multi-programme issue) so if it doesn't match I would just have "old/closed programme"
- Programme keys are always the same number of characters, its actually 8 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` to compare the delimited list to your value by surrounding both with delimiter characters:

```sql
SELECT pj.project,
       pj.programme_key,
       pg.programme_key AS active_programme_key,
       pg.programme
FROM   project pj
       LEFT OUTER JOIN programmes pg
       ON ( '; ' || pj.programme_key || '; ' LIKE '%; ' || pg.programme_key || '; %' );
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE project ( PROJECT, PROGRAMME_KEY ) AS
SELECT 'AAA', '55171; 55174; 55175' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BBB', '55173' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCC', '55178; 55172; ' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE programmes ( PROGRAMME, PROGRAMME_KEY ) AS
SELECT 'XXX',  55171 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'YYY',  55172 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZZZZ', 55173 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> PROJECT | PROGRAMME_KEY       | ACTIVE_PROGRAMME_KEY | PROGRAMME
> :------ | :------------------ | -------------------: | :--------
> AAA     | 55171; 55174; 55175 |                55171 | XXX      
> BBB     | 55173               |                55173 | ZZZZ     
> CCC     | 55178; 55172;       |                55172 | YYY
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8aececb4d49095625635b872160d1364)*

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a go at this one first as I'm still a bit of a novice at SQL and this one makes the most sense to me!

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much, you've saved us a lot of text to column faffing around in excel

Answer (score 1):

For example (read comments within code):

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data; you already have that, don't type it
  3  project (project, pkey) as
  4    (select 'AAA', '55171; 55174; 55175' from dual union all
  5     select 'BBB', '55173'               from dual union all
  6     select 'CCC', '55178; 55172;'       from dual
  7    ),
  8  programme (programme, pkey) as
  9    (select 'XXX', '55171' from dual union all
 10     select 'YYY', '55172' from dual union all
 11     select 'ZZZ', '55173' from dual
 12    ),
 13  -- This is where your query actually begins.
 14  -- Split projects's PKEY into rows so that you could join them to programme's PKEY
 15  projsplit as
 16    (select project,
 17            trim(regexp_substr(pkey, '[^;]+', 1, column_value)) pkey
 18     from project cross join
 19          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 20                              connect by level <= regexp_count(pkey, ';') + 1
 21                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 22    )
 23  -- Join PROJSPLIT with PROGRAMME
 24  select a.project, a.pkey, b.programme, b.pkey,
 25    case when a.pkey = b.pkey then 'Yes, it exists'
 26         else 'No, it does not exist'
 27    end status
 28  from projsplit a left join programme b on a.pkey = b.pkey
 29  order by a.project, a.pkey;

PRO PKEY  PRO PKEY  STATUS
--- ----- --- ----- ---------------------
AAA 55171 XXX 55171 Yes, it exists
AAA 55174           No, it does not exist
AAA 55175           No, it does not exist
BBB 55173 ZZZ 55173 Yes, it exists
CCC 55172 YYY 55172 Yes, it exists
CCC 55178           No, it does not exist
CCC                 No, it does not exist

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm going to try the other answer first but if thats not working for me I'll try this one. Sorry I'm new at stackoverflow so not sure if I need to respond to people or not

Comment: You're welcome. No problem in commenting, of course. What exactly doesn't work? It shows that - according to sample data you posted - certain combinations exist or not, so ... from my point of view, it *works*.